# How to use jQuery autocomplete correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use autocomplete from

http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js

but am getting this error. `textbox` is the id of the input field where autocomplete should happen:

> [image]

I have tried to follow the example given on [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete). **What am I doing wrong here?**

---

Getting the same error on using `ready`:

[image]

Comment: have u include latest `jquery` and writing above code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //here });`

Comment: @diEcho: getting the same error (question updated).

Comment: It works now, I just reloaded the files, something was not in sync I think. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have NOT included the script yet. Put this in the head of your page and test.

```
<script  src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"/>
```

Comment: It works now, I just reloaded the files, something was not in sync I think. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

include `jquery.js` and `autocomplete.js` on the top of page and write the code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// right here
});
```